Unable to define Custom Proxy Port Element Type in EA17
Using the Sparx Enterprise Architect V17 software, when creating a proxy port, the target Element (From a MDG Stereotype) cannot be selected in the Properties window, on the Property tab, Type definition.
When the Property Type is selected, the Stereotype displayed only includes SysML1.4 class elements. This problem does not occur in previous versions, such as 15.1 and 15.2.
If target a SysML 1.4 Element, like an Interface block, I can select it. But the custom Stereotype I can´t.

Has anyone encountered this behavior?
Thanks in advance!

I have the same problem!

It's not a bug, but an improvement.
The SysML specification states in the constraints of ProxyPort


2_interfaceblock
Proxy ports shall only be typed by interface blocks.
InterfaceBlock.allInstances().base_Class->includes(self.base_Port.type)


So EA correctly implements this constraint by not letting you select anything else then InterfaceBlocks

Geert, thank you so much for the context. The Custom stereotyped element I intend to connect is a generalization of the SysML1.4::Interface. I have a lengthy implementation that uses this custom element, so I need to rethink it or find a workaround.

If your stereotype is a specialization of the SysML InterfaceBlock stereotype, then you would have a case. And you probably will, because I'm not sure if EA's constraints check for specializations of a stereotype.
